# Celery remains process opened

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a problem with Celery. I have set Celery to run demonized. This is the command:

> /home/user/sitios/incidencias/env/bin/python3 -m celery worker --concurrency=4 --time-limit=200 --app=incidencias --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker1%I.log --pidfile …

The problem is that celery run too many processes and finally collapse the system.
Here a htop snapshot:

[image: Htop Snapshot]

I have set a time-limit of 200 but it seems be ignored. How can I prevent this? I'm noob with celery.

Note: I have tasks calling tasks.

Comment: By "too many processes", did you mean celery will create processes indefinitely or just these 12 processes in the picture?

Comment: This is a catch at 12 hours of operation (more or less). It creates processes until it ends up blocking the system.

Comment: Are you running a threaded program by any chance? Htop will show a row for each thread (You could press 'H' to hide them).